# Create html table from fields in foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that displays custom fields as an html form:

```
<?php foreach ( $job_fields as $key => $field ) : ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset-<?php esc_attr_e( $key ); ?>">
            <label for="<?php esc_attr_e( $key ); ?>"><?php echo $field['label'] . apply_filters( 'submit_job_form_required_label', $field['required'] ? '' : ' <small>' . __( '(optional)', 'wp-job-manager' ) . '</small>', $field ); ?></label>
            <div class="field <?php echo $field['required'] ? 'required-field' : ''; ?>">
                <?php get_job_manager_template( 'form-fields/' . $field['type'] . '-field.php', array( 'key' => $key, 'field' => $field ) ); ?>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Is there way to customize this code to display he fields in an html table instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace  etc. with  etc. 
Create your blank HTML table first, then place all the  in the proper places.